# Running Gatling from docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gatling

I have the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'

services:

  gatling:
    image: denvazh/gatling
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./conf:/opt/gatling/conf
      - ./user-files:/opt/gatling/user-files
      - ./results:/opt/gatling/results
```

When I run it with `docker-compose up` I get the list of all simulations, but when I choose mine, something strange happens:

```
dc up
Creating gatling_gatling_1
Attaching to gatling_gatling_1
gatling_1 | GATLING_HOME is set to /opt/gatling
gatling_1 | Choose a simulation number:
gatling_1 |      [0] AppsPods
gatling_1 |      [1] ServerSimulation
gatling_1 |      [2] computerdatabase.BasicSimulation
gatling_1 |      [3] computerdatabase.advanced.AdvancedSimulationStep01
gatling_1 |      [4] computerdatabase.advanced.AdvancedSimulationStep02
gatling_1 |      [5] computerdatabase.advanced.AdvancedSimulationStep03
gatling_1 |      [6] computerdatabase.advanced.AdvancedSimulationStep04
gatling_1 |      [7] computerdatabase.advanced.AdvancedSimulationStep05
0
ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon - you might need to run `docker-machine start default`.
```

As you see there are no other questions in terminal about the simulation.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

There is a known bug when `up` is used with `tty: True` (https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3106). I believe you're hitting a timeout after a while and the error is being reported incorrectly.

If you want something more interactive you could try using `docker-compose run` instead, which doesn't have this issue.